# Is there a reason why OnePlus devices don't have the Build.VERSION.RELEASE_OR_CODENAME value

Tags: java, android, exception

The following code works on Samsung devices to get the Android version number:
`String buildVersionRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE_OR_CODENAME;`

The same code returns this error on OnePlus devices (3T and 5T)

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field RELEASE_OR_CODENAME of type Ljava/lang/String; in class Landroid/os/Build$VERSION; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.os.Build$VERSION' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
```

Comment: What OS are you running them on? According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION#RELEASE_OR_CODENAME   that value was added in API 30 (Android 11).

Comment: ah, that explains it, onepluses are under android 9 and 10, samsungs are all running android 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take it with just using release. You can't get it always because it's working by device situation(is rooted etc.). So if you want to get it below code should work:

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Comment: so OnePlus doesn't use the CODENAME field?

Comment: It's an old approach :) Because Version and codename fields both may be set at the same time. Which one it will get in this case?